# How to say when you collect exam papers

Tags: phrase-request

In a situation that I am a teacher in a class and I have an exam in class.

Each student has a problem sheet. At the end of the exam, when I collect exam, I want to tell students that the students who sit at the rear seat in the room first pass his/her exam to students sitting in front of him or her , and so on.

Is there any short way to say this in class? Any useful phrase that is common in this situation?

Comment: Students in the rear seats, please pass your exam paper to the front

Comment: Privacy issues aside, I would say, "Please pass your exams to the person in front of you."

Answer (score 1):

A usual and clear way to give this instruction is to say

> Please pass your exam papers forward to the person in front of you, starting with the last row.

The short form is

> Please pass you exam papers forward.